# is it possible to build a map without gmapping and keyboard teleop?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a picture of a room and i want to load this picture or the coordinates of the room into turtlebot and convert it to map through rviz.. any idea ?
thanks in advance..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189224/is-it-possible-to-build-a-map-without-gmapping-and-keyboard-teleop?/) by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the purpose of AMCL (monte carlo localization as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map)) on a turtlebot, maps are saved as .pgm's (portable grey maps), where each cell indicates one of three values: occupied, unoccupied, or unknown.You can learn more [here](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server). If you have some occupancy data of this room then it's possible to convert it into a suitable .pgm. However, to my mind, there's no package or work done in taking a picture of a room and converting it into a .pgm...

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1